# AngularVelocity relative to a CameraRig (VR)

Tags: unity-game-engine, quaternions, rigid-bodies

Im in a bit of a pickle. I am working on trying to make objects that I release from my hand in VR adopt the correct velocity and angularVelocity of the controller so their release movement feels natural. This is a simple matter of tracking the controller angularvelocity and velocity and passing it to the opbject upon release:

```
 rigid.velocity = controller.currentVelocity;
 rigid.angularVelocity = controller.currentAngularVelocity;
```

However, and here comes the kicker, I also have a locomotion system that happens to rotate the CameraRig with regards to the head of the player and after doing so these values are all wrong and shifted with regards to the cameraRig as so:

```
 cameraRig.transform.RotateAround(headsetCamera.transform.position, Vector3.up, -(headsetCamera.transform.eulerAngles.y - lastHeadRot.y));
 lastHeadRot = headsetCamera.transform.eulerAngles;
```

I have tried looking for some answers like this ([ref](http://answers.unity.com/comments/917563/view.html)) and this ([ref](http://answers.unity.com/answers/239882/view.html)) but none of it has worked. Any suggestions would be most welcome. When using other forms of locomotion the angularvelocity and velocity get set correctly to the objects thrown but not once I have used the rotateAround on the cameraRig.

Comment: Tried to transform the vector its hopes that would work with:
`rigid.angularVelocity = controller.transform.TransformVector(currentAngularVelocity);`

but sadly no luck.

Comment: Also tried:
`localAngularVelocity = transform.InverseTransformVector(currentAngularVelocity);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this finally, so I thought I would add the solution here.

Instead of using this code to throw objects:

```
 _rigid.velocity = controller.currentVelocity;
 _rigid.angularVelocity = controller.currentAngularVelocity;
```

I used:

```
 _rigid.AddForce(controller.currentVelocity);
 _rigid.angularVelocity = controller.currentAngularVelocity;
```

this solved the issue and the objects now fly in the expected direction no matter what the roation of the parent is.